# Video converted using ffmpeg does not have fast forward feature

Tags: ffmpeg

I used the following command to convert the video codec:

```
ffmpeg  -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

When I play the output.mp4 I observe than the fast forward feature is not enabled. Any one have similar problems?

Comment: What feature? Where are you playing the video when you say "it's not enabled"? Please also post the full, uncut command line output!

Comment: The fast forward feature where i can speed up the video (fast forward). I am playing it on my tv. What exactly do you mean by uncut command line input.

Comment: I mean command line **output**. What does FFmpeg output in your console?

Comment: Okay. I guess I finally figured it out. The TV requires a specific minimum length to enable fast forwarding. Since the clip was extremely small it refused to do so.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Please answer your own question then!